# RAM usage for webadmin

Tags: python, ram-usage

I would like to know RAM usage.
I know there are several commands like free, top, but how can i get only the number in MB's like "3172", so i can use it in my webadmin script?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming from the given commands you mean shell commands:

Depending on which value you want you can use something like

```
free -m | awk '/^-/ {print $4}'
```

The regex between the two `/` selects the line you want (here it's the one starting with `-`), the number after the `$` denotes the field you want (here it's the 4th).

Answer (score 0):

`free` gets its information from the special file `/proc/meminfo`. I'm not that good at Python, but I guess you can read the "file" line by line and split it on `:`.